# Modal box Problems I my modal box does not close for some reason

Tags: javascript

I want to make modal boxes for two images. The modal box is opening, but it cannot be closed.

[Here is my  script](http://jsfiddle.net/IyamSIM/dncgc42t)

```
...
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        lol.style.display = "none";
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Improved spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code after fixing 
http://jsfiddle.net/dncgc42t/4/

The problem was that you have a lot of `span`s with the class `close`   , so you should loop over them, because when you use `document.getElmentsByClassName('close')[0]` this will always return only the first element with class `close` so other elements will not effected.

**On the other hand**

Using `class` over `id` for modals will be better.

Answer (score 0):

You use two spans, only one of them is added an onclick event because you use the [0] index. Adding the second one with the [1] index will work, but you'll be better of with a for loop.

Also note that you can probably create a single modal window class. Only one is visible at a time.

Below a working version with the for loop

```
  var i;
  for( i=0; i<span.length; i++)
  {
     span[i].onclick = function() {
      box.style.display = "none";
      lol.style.display = "none";
     }
  }
```

[New JSFiddle, click here](http://jsfiddle.net/txgxeyn9/)

Comment: Too late, oh well ;)